# API REST don't work routes

Tags: codeigniter, api, routes, codeigniter-restserver

I'm using codeigniter, for make an api rest, with the library that provide the oficial web site.

The problem is: the file routes.php doesn't redirect well. When i put ***localhost/API/1*** into my browser apear the 404 error.

Here my controller "Apicontroller":

```
public function __construct() { //constructor //no tocar
    parent::__construct();
    $this -> load -> model("Modelocontrolador");
}

public function index_get() { //get all the info
    $datos_devueltos = $this->Modelocontrolador->getPrueba(NULL, "Usuarios"); 

    if(!is_null($datos_devueltos)){
       $this->response(array("response" => $datos_devueltos), 200);
    }else{
       $this->response(array("response" => "No date"), 200); 
    }
}
public function  find_get($id){ //select where
    $datos_devueltos = $this->Modelocontrolador->getPrueba($id, "Usuarios");
    if($id != NULL){
        if(!is_null($datos_devueltos)){
           $this->response(array("response" => $datos_devueltos), 200);
        }else{
           $this->response(array("response" => "No date"), 200); 
        }
    }else{
        $this->response(array("response" => "No dates for search"), 200); 
    }
}

public function index_post() { //insert in la table
    if(! $this -> post("dato")){
        $this->response(array("response" => "No enought info"), 200); 
    }else{
        $datoID = $this -> Modelocontrolador -> save($this -> post("dato"),"UsuariosJJ");

        if(!is_null($datoID)){
           $this->response(array("response" => $datoID), 200); 
        }else{
           $this->response(array("response" => "No found it"), 200); 
        }
    }
}
public function index_put($id) { //"update"
    if(! $this -> post("dato") || ! $id){
        $this->response(array("response" => "No ha mandado informacion correcta para el update"), 200); 
    }else{
        $datoID = $this -> Modelocontrolador -> update("Uid",$id,$this -> post("dato"),"UsuariosJJ");

        if(!is_null($datoID)){
           $this->response(array("response" => "Dato actualizado"), 200); 
        }else{
           $this->response(array("response" => "Error modify"), 200); 
        }
    }

}
public function index_delete($id) {
    if(! $id){
        $this->response(array("response" => "Not enought info"), 200); 
    }else{
        $delete = $this-> Modelocontrolador -> delete("Uid",$id,"UsuariosJJ");
    }

    if(!is_null($delete)){
        $this->response(array("response" => "Date delete"), 200); 
    }else{
        $this->response(array("response" => "Error delete"), 200); 
    }

}}
```

And my routes file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Apicontroller';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

/*sub-rutas*/
/*---------*/
$route["Apicontroller"]["get"] = "Apicontroller/index"; //basico
$route["Apicontroller/(:num)"]["get"] = "Apicontroller/find"; //select
$route["Apicontroller"]["post"] = "Apicontroller/index"; //insert
$route["Apicontroller/(:num)"]["put"] = "Apicontroller/index/$1"; //update
$route["Apicontroller/(:num)"]["delete"] = "Apicontroller/index/$1"; //delete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the browser request literally uses **/API** then routing needs to 'see' exactly that. Also, the route rules must be explicit with the method to be called. (Hopefully the code shown reflects the mapping you had in mind.)

```
/*sub-rutas*/
/*---------*/
$route["API"]["get"] = "Apicontroller/index_get"; //basico
$route["API/(:num)"]["get"] = "Apicontroller/find_get/$1"; //select
$route["API"]["post"] = "Apicontroller/index_post"; //insert
$route["API/(:num)"]["put"] = "Apicontroller/index_put/$1"; //update
$route["API/(:num)"]["delete"] = "Apicontroller/index_delete/$1"; //delete
```

Using the above routes I created some test code. Here are those files.

The much simplified Apicontroller.

```
class Apicontroller extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function index_get()
  {
    echo "API index";
  }

  public function find_get($id)
  { //select where
    echo "API find_get $id";
  }

  public function index_post()
  {
    echo 'API index_post';
  }

  public function index_put($id)
  { //"update"
    echo "API put $id";
  }
}
```

I don't believe that because your Apicontroller is extending a different Class the results would change. That may be a drastic assumption.

In order to test POST calls I used these two files. 
First a Testpost.php controller

```
class Testpost extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view("test");
  }

}
```

The very simple view (test.php) loaded by the above.

```
<?php
echo form_open("API");
echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!');
echo form_close();
```

Directing the browser to **localhost/testpost** shows a page with a single submit button. Pressing the button results in a screen with the text "API index_post".

Sending the browser to **localhost/API/3** produces a screen with the text "API find_get 3".

**localhost/API** produces "API index".

Now the interesting thing (not related to your problem, but interesting).

Given the default

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Apicontroller';
```

and the route

```
$route["API"]["get"] = "Apicontroller/index_get";
```

I expected that directing the browser to the home page **localhost** would produce "API index". But it doesn't. It results in a 404. Due to that behavior it might be wise to be more explicit with default_controller

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Apicontroller/index_get';
```

Or add an `index()` function to Apicontroller that calls `$this->index_get()`.

I did not test PUT or DELETE as my server isn't setup to handle them. But as GET and POST seem to function, in a righteous world, they will work.

Comment: Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

Comment: Does the first line of the controller look like this `class Apicontroller extends CI_Controller {` ?  And is it named (case sensitive) Apicontroller.php? And it is in the `application/controllers/ folder?

Comment: Try changing the first route to `$route["API"] = "Apicontroller/index_get"; //basico` and enter 'localhost/API' in the browser. Get anywhere?

Comment: The problem continue when i try make the operation get: "localhost/API/1" if i make "localhost/API" work.

Comment: And this is the name of the controller (into my controllers folder) Apicontroller.php and the class are: "class Apicontroller extends REST_Controller".

Comment: And i have the library REST_Controller imported into libraries

Comment: Everything seems to be setup correctly. I tested the code and it works for me. At one point I did need to clear the browser cache in order for newly edited code to run.

Comment: DFriend, can you pass me project into a zip then?

Comment: Ha, ha. I was revising my answer to include the test files while you were asking for them.

Comment: dosn't matter, if you want i pass you an email for this

Comment: Sure. Where do I send it?

Comment: roberburnday@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are using PHil's REST_Controller library with CI 2.x, correct ?

If so, I would recommend you to use what I like to call an "index gateway" because you can't do per-Method routing with CI2:

```
class Apicontroller extends REST_Controller
{
  function index_gateway_get($id){
    $this->get_get($id);
  }

  function index_gateway_put($id){
    $this->put_put($id);
  }

  // This is not a "gateway" method because POST doesn't require an ID
  function index_post(){
    $this->post_post();
  }

  function get_get($id = null){
    if(!isset($id)){
      // Get all rows
    }else{
      // Get specific row
    }
  }

  function put_put($id = null){
    if(!isset($id)){
      // a PUT withtout an ID is a POST
      $this->post_post();
    }else{
      // PUT method
    }
  }

  function post_post(){
    // POST method
  }
}
```

The routing to make this work is really easy:

```
$route["API/(:num)"] = "Apicontroller/index_gateway/$1";
```

That's all you need. Phil's REST Library will redirect to the correct `index_gateway_HTTPMETHOD` depending on which method is used. 
Each `index_gateway_HTTPMETHOD` will then redirect to the correct method.

As far as I know, this trick is the only way to have CI2 use a single /API/ entry point that works for all HTTP Methods.